# Django TruncDay limit by largest grouping

Tags: django, postgresql, time-series, django-queryset, limit

I am trying to draw a day series graph, whereby it will show the number of employees of the division(s) in a day series. The problem here is that I want to find a way to limit to the division with the most employees so I dont need to draw too many lines and stress the database. (for example limit it to top 3 division with the most employee attendance)

I am using:
Django 1.11.x
Postgres 9.4

The goal is to create a day series graphing of this sort. has the grouping of division and the number of employee.

[image: graphing]

I have manage to achieve it with the following code:

```
from datetime import date, datetime
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import (
    TruncDate, TruncDay, TruncHour, TruncMinute, TruncSecond,
    )

emp_by_day = Attendance.objects.annotate(day=TruncDay('created_at')).values('day', 'division_id').annotate(cnt=Count('employee_id', distinct = True)).order_by('day')

for exp in emp_by_day:
    print(exp['day'], exp['division_id'], exp['cnt'])
```

however, it currently output displays like this (i am generally happy but want to limit it):

```
              employee count<->
              division_id<->
<---day----------------->
2019-10-22 00:00:00+00:00 15 6
2019-10-22 00:00:00+00:00 16 6
2019-10-22 00:00:00+00:00 18 5
2019-10-22 00:00:00+00:00 20 4
2019-10-22 00:00:00+00:00 21 12 <-- largest 3
2019-10-22 00:00:00+00:00 25 14 <-- largest 3
2019-10-22 00:00:00+00:00 28 12 <-- largest 3
2019-10-23 00:00:00+00:00 15 6
2019-10-23 00:00:00+00:00 16 5
2019-10-23 00:00:00+00:00 18 2
2019-10-23 00:00:00+00:00 20 3
2019-10-23 00:00:00+00:00 21 14 <-- largest 3
2019-10-23 00:00:00+00:00 25 17 <-- largest 3
2019-10-23 00:00:00+00:00 28 13 <-- largest 3
2019-10-24 00:00:00+00:00 15 2
2019-10-24 00:00:00+00:00 16 6
2019-10-24 00:00:00+00:00 18 5
2019-10-24 00:00:00+00:00 20 4
2019-10-24 00:00:00+00:00 21 13 <-- largest 3
2019-10-24 00:00:00+00:00 25 12 <-- largest 3
2019-10-24 00:00:00+00:00 28 10 <-- largest 3
```

my goal is to produce this (limit it to the largest 3 division):

```
2019-10-22 00:00:00+00:00 21 12 <-- largest 3
2019-10-22 00:00:00+00:00 25 14 <-- largest 3
2019-10-22 00:00:00+00:00 28 12 <-- largest 3
2019-10-23 00:00:00+00:00 21 14 <-- largest 3
2019-10-23 00:00:00+00:00 25 17 <-- largest 3
2019-10-23 00:00:00+00:00 28 13 <-- largest 3
2019-10-24 00:00:00+00:00 21 13 <-- largest 3
2019-10-24 00:00:00+00:00 25 12 <-- largest 3
2019-10-24 00:00:00+00:00 28 10 <-- largest 3
```

Do let me know how can I produce such an intended output (limit it to the largest 3 division)

Comment: Can I provide solution in SQL. I am not very well in ORM. However, I will try to post the solution in that too.

Comment: Do you want to limit it to top 3 division with the most employee attendance at the current day, or on average over the report time or on ... ?

Comment: yes top 3 division with the most employee attendance at the current day, and use that 3 for the time series. anyway if there are others that make sense its fine, as long as i can limit it in the query of something top 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Rank()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Rank) window function to filter out results.

**Logic:**

*Assuming that you want grouping per `day`*

You should give a rank to each row based on the count `cnt` value partitioned over day. The highest will get 1st rank and so on. Now you should filter out the result which has rank between 1 to 3.

Continuing your query

```
emp_by_day.annotate(rank=Window(
expression=Rank(),
order_by=F('cnt').desc(),
partition_by=[F('day')])).filter(rank__range=(1,3))
```

**Note:** In case of same value of `cnt` for more than one row, the rank will be same for two or more rows. Hence you can get more than 3 rows. If you want only first 3 rows then use [`RowNumber()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#rownumber) instead of `Rank()`.

**Postgres Example Query:**

```
select * from (
 select *, rank() over (partition by day order by cnt desc) as rank from 
 (
  select emp_id,day,count(emp_id) as cnt from attendance group by emp_id,day  
  order by day
 ) as T
) as Temp where rank between 1 and 3;
```

Replace [`rank()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-window.html) by [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-window.html) to get only first 3 rows.

**Update**

Django 1.11 does not supports `window()`. However you can refer [following gist](https://gist.github.com/hassanselim0/8123bf889c4df4879993ae11bab335f6) which back-ports this functionality from Django 2 to 1.11.

**Note:** I have not tested it. However, the OP creator tested it and it works.

Comment: AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects' <-- this error appear after i execute your query above

Comment: Wow, nice solution. Wasn't aware of that.

Comment: django 1.11 does not support --->  django.db.models import Window, probably its a nice solution.

Comment: @Axil If it is helpful then kindly vote up and if it solves your task then accept the answer. The answer is already edited to address the first issue you raised in comments.

Comment: @Axil If you have any other query then kindly mention

Comment: im not sure it actually solves it but will still vote up. i think the query should happen before not as a continuation. i think you are trying to rank it top 3 of the results. i want a way to limit the query at the beginning to the top 3 largest so that it doesnt need to query the whole division of the time series. also, i dont think it supports for django 1.11, would need to try the raw sql though.

Comment: @Axil How you will come to know the top three at the beginning? As far as I know the aggregate as well as window function are applied after grouping, hence you cannot use there alias column name in where clause. Once you get count & rank then only you will be able to filter it out. Hence, you had to continue the query Let me see if I can figure out something ( Chances are low). By the way, you can clarify more about what you mean If I am getting it wrong.

Comment: oh i get it. you are right. what you are doing is nice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201755/discussion-between-axil-and-geeksal).

Comment: actually it didnt work:
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: window functions are not allowed in WHERE
LINE 1: ..." >= '2016-11-02T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz AND RANK() OVE...

Comment: In discussion you said it worked and you accepted the answer. However, I will try to help you out. You need to provide the db table sql script with data, so that I can reproduce it. I will provide you the SQL query which you can try to translate in Django ORM.

Comment: Also you cannot use the window function in where clause. As the aggregate and window functions are applied after filtering (i.e. after where clause). See the SQL query I had provided there is a reason I had use multiple select statement (and it is same as I stated above) Try to do it like I have done in answer. The answer is quite correct based on what you asked. If you missed something create a new OP.

Answer (score 1):

First find out what the divisions you want to graph are (let's call that set `best_divisions`) and then filter them in your query.

```
Attendance.objects.filter(division__in=best_divisions).annotate(day=…
```

In order to find the divisions you can for example:

```
best_divitions = Division.objects.annotate(
    total_attendance=Count("attendance__employee", distinct=True),
).order_by("-total_attendance")[:3]
```

Comment: this looks like quite close, best_divisions, somehow i think takes the whole amount. how can we get the top 3 for the current day/month/year ?

Comment: and then use that as the best_divisions to filter. I like this idea, but i want to pick the top 3 division for the current day/month/year (not for the whole database) - we can use day as an example

Comment: In your solution you're also not specifying any time range. Use subquery to count only the annotations you're interested in for determining the best division. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Comment: as Im using TruncDay, it is time series/range